# LeanFT is unable to take screenshot

Tags: java, hp-uft, leanft

I try to take screenshot from current page under test with `LeanFT` to attach to report file.

```
RenderedImage img = browser.getPage().getSnapshot();
Reporter.reportEvent("Login","Login successful", Status.Passed, img);
```

I get error message:

> com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: ERROR at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory.createDefault(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:202)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory.createOrDefault(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:194)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory.createOrDefault(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:21)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectExecuterBehaviorBase$ReplayErrorHandler.onError(TestObjectExecuterBehaviorBase.java:65)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.handleError(CommunicationClientImpl.java:221)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.send(CommunicationClientImpl.java:96)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectExecuterBehavior.executeMethod(TestObjectExecuter.java:44)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectBase.executeMethod(TestObjectBase.java:123)
>   at
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectBase.getSnapshot(TestObjectBase.java:197)

Method in reference(https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/JavaSDKReference/com/hp/lft/report/Reporter.html):

> reportEvent(java.lang.String stepName, java.lang.String description,
>   Status status, java.lang.Exception ex, java.awt.image.RenderedImage
>   image) Adds a custom step to the LeanFT including the provided
>   exception and image object.

Comment: The Exception is raised in getSnapshot() according to the stackTrace - does not even reaches the Report. Possible causes - mostly the Object does not exist or is not fully loaded. An exotic cause might be that LeanFT cannot use the Image Capture Driver.

Comment: I imported all the necessary classes. How could I continue debugging?

Comment: My comment was not related to imports but to the browser Object. Is it visible on the screen, does the exist() method returns true? what about the object returned by getPage() afterwards. Only if the UI Obejcts represented by these 2 methods are visible the screenshot will be taken

Comment: I get NullPointerexception for browser.exists() , but I use browser on the same class.

Comment: then something is not okay with your browser variable. Is not initalized. Can you share the full code?

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa : I use this code:
`Browser browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);
    browser.navigate(env.LOGIN);`

Comment: also, no need to get the snapshot of the page, do it directly on the `browser`: `browser.getSnapshot()`

Comment: @Adelin : I already tried that too.

Comment: It occurs with Firefox as well? Or Phantom JS? What OS is this? Try updating chrome and LeanFT

Comment: @Adelin : It happens with Chrome and it is already the newest one.

Comment: What LeanFT version are you using? What is the browser agent version?

Comment: @Adelin : I use LeanFT 14.02 and plugin version 14.3.3652.1.

Comment: That could be the problem. The plugin version is ahead. You should try to downgrade to 14.2 (or update leanft)